# What are the differences among grep, awk & sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

I am confused about the differences between `grep`, `awk` and `sed` in terms of their role in Unix/Linux system administration and text processing.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Short definition:

`grep`: search for specific terms in a file

```
#usage
$ grep This file.txt
Every line containing "This"
Every line containing "This"
Every line containing "This"
Every line containing "This"

$ cat file.txt
Every line containing "This"
Every line containing "This"
Every line containing "That"
Every line containing "This"
Every line containing "This"
```

Now `awk` and `sed` are completly different than `grep`.
`awk` and `sed` are text processors. Not only do they have the ability to find what you are looking for in text, they have the ability to remove, add and modify the text as well (and much more).

`awk` is mostly used for data extraction and reporting. `sed` is a stream editor
Each one of them has its own functionality and specialties.

Example 
Sed

```
$ sed -i 's/cat/dog/' file.txt
# this will replace any occurrence of the characters 'cat' by 'dog'
```

Awk

```
$ awk '{print $2}' file.txt
# this will print the second column of file.txt
```

Basic `awk` usage:
Compute sum/average/max/min/etc. what ever you may need.

```
$ cat file.txt
A 10
B 20
C 60
$ awk 'BEGIN {sum=0; count=0; OFS="\t"} {sum+=$2; count++} END {print "Average:", sum/count}' file.txt
Average:    30
```

I recommend that you read this book: [Sed & Awk: 2nd Ed.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565922255)

It will help you become a proficient sed/awk user on any unix-like environment.

Answer (score 65):

Grep is useful if you want to quickly search for lines that match in a file. It can also return some other simple information like matching line numbers, match count, and file name lists.

Awk is an entire programming language built around reading CSV-style files, processing the records, and optionally printing out a result data set. It can do many things but it is not the easiest tool to use for simple tasks.

Sed is useful when you want to make changes to a file based on regular expressions. It allows you to easily match parts of lines, make modifications, and print out results. It's less expressive than awk but that lends it to somewhat easier use for simple tasks. It has many more complicated operators you can use (I think it's even turing complete), but in general you won't use those features.

Comment: One can search for a lines in a file with AWK as much fast as with Grep. That's the first case described here: [grep vs awk : 10 examples of pattern search (theunixschool)](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/09/grep-vs-awk-examples-for-pattern-search.html).

Answer (score 35):

I just want to mention a thing, there are many tools can do text processing, e.g.
sort, cut, split, join, paste, comm, uniq, column, rev, tac, tr, nl, pr, head, tail.....

they are very handy but you have to learn their options etc.

A lazy way (not the best way) to learn text processing might be: only learn grep , sed and awk. with this three tools, you can solve almost 99% of text processing problems and don't need to memorize above different cmds and options. :)

AND, if you 've learned and used the three, you knew the difference. Actually, the difference here means which tool is good at solving what kind of problem.

a more lazy way might be learning a script language (python, perl or ruby) and do every text processing with it.

Comment: Depends on the complexity of the job to do aside of the pattern matching. If there is a lot of logic aside of pattern magic, Python will be a better option, if the surrounding logic is more simple, SEd/Grep/AWK.

Comment: Actually, following this line of reasoning you could recommend to just learn and use awk since it can do most of what sed and grep can.

Comment: This should not be an answer because it does not answer the OPs question.